# Open Trip Planner doesn't seem to be accounting for turn restrictions - editing local OSM pbfs for scenario planning

Tags: openstreetmap, pbf, josm, opentripplanner

We've been attempting to use Open Trip Planner (1.5) to test the impact of various street-network scenarios that include new ways, traffic filtering and vehicle turning restrictions. We are manually editing a local OSM .pbf offline using JOSM to insert and tag the new ways and nodes. For proposed turning restrictions, we have tried both using the JOSM plug-in "turnrestrictions" and directly editing relationships.

When routing, Open Trip Planner appears to recognize new ways and correctly considers tags regarding directionality, max speed, etc. But it appears, however, to systematically ignore newly created turn restrictions. (We've tried with the r5 routing engine, as well. No luck.)

In the first image, you see the routing results when we remove a link in Foreland Road. OTP identifies an alternative route.

[image: Map showing expected route after removal of way]

In the second image, you see the results of creating a new way--"Testing Road" -- to replace the deleted Foreland Road and inserting turn restrictions that should prevent a left turn from Steyne to Testing and a right turn from Testing to Swains. In this case, OTP properly makes use of the new way but completely ignores the new turn restrictions.

[image: Map showing unexpected routing behaviour]

We double checked and the coding for the relations containing the restrictions appears to match the format of other "existing" restrictions.

[image: Screenshot of JOSM showing turn-restriction coding]